# how can i dump the contents of the EEProm in my Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: boot, bootloader

I had fiddled with a few things while trying to get my Pi4 to boot from USB (its working now) and i want to make sure i didnt screw anything up.

does sudo rpi-eeprom-config show the contents of the EEPROM?
when i run I only see 3 lines

BOOT_UART

WAKE_ON

POWER_OFF

i dont see anything about boot order

my /etc/defaults/rpi-eeprom-update file only has a single line

FIRMWARE ... =default

Is that correct

Comment: one way to see boot order is [documented here](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#boot-diagnostics-on-the-raspberry-pi-4)